# Approximating spectra of (finite rank pertubations of) Laurent operators by spectra of (pertubations of) periodic finite operators

Tags: matrices, mp.mathematical-physics, sp.spectral-theory, open-problems, differential-operators

A tridiagonal matrix is a matrix which only has elements on three diagonals.
So for $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \mathbb{C}$ consider the bi-infinite tridiagonal Laurent operator $T$  with $\beta $ on the diagonal given by.

\begin{pmatrix}
\dots &  \dots & \dots & \dots  & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\ 
 \dots & \alpha & \beta & \gamma & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots \\ 
\dots & 0 & \alpha & \beta & \gamma & 0 & 0 & \dots\\ 
\dots &  0 & 0 & \alpha & \beta  & \gamma & 0 & \dots\\ 
\dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \alpha & \beta & \gamma &  \dots \\ 
\dots &  \dots & \dots & \dots  & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\ 
\end{pmatrix}

General theory tells us that $T$ is invertible if and only the symbol curve (which is in this case is an ellipsis) given by
$
\{ z \in \mathbb{T} \mid \frac{\alpha}{z} + \beta + z \gamma \} 
$
does not enclose $0$.

In finite dimensions, we can consider the periodic version $T_n$. For example $T_5$ looks as follows:

\begin{pmatrix}
 \beta & \gamma & 0 & 0 &  \alpha   \\ 
 \alpha & \beta & \gamma & 0 & 0  \\ 
0 & \alpha & \beta & \gamma & 0  \\ 
  0 & 0 & \alpha & \beta  & \gamma  \\ 
\gamma & 0 & 0 &  \alpha & \beta \\ 
\end{pmatrix}

Now, when $n$ tends to $\infty$ then the spectra of the periodic versions $\sigma(T_n)$ approximate the spectrum of the Laurent operator $T$. In the sense that in Haussdorff distance it holds that

$$
\sigma(T_n) \to \sigma(T). 
$$
This can for example be seen by Fourier Transform.

Now, suppose that I add finitely many diagonal terms. I.e. the matrix $K = \text{diag}(K_{1,1}, K_{2,2} , \dots, K_{m,m})$.

Then it is a Theorem (see https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01275512, Corollary 1.3)  that
$$
lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \sigma(T_n + P_n K P_n) \cup \sigma(T) \right) \to \sigma(T+K). 
$$
Here $P_n$ is the projection onto the $n$ sites of $T_n$.

But in general it is conjectured (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01275512, Conjecture 7.3)  that
$$
lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \sigma(T_n + P_n K P_n) \right) \to \sigma(T+K). 
$$
Meaning that the finite system can also approximate the symbol curve as was the case without the pertubation.
What is the status of this conjecture? And in the case $m=1$ where the pertubation is only a single entry, how could one go about proving it?

The reason I am interested is given on page 18 in here https://arxiv.org/pdf/2206.09879.pdf, where one can see that these question can help answer to what extend the spectra of some infinite volume open quantum systems are approximated by their finite volume periodic counterparts.